# elastic search: how to query_string with insensitive case?

Tags: elasticsearch

Right now I'm using query_string to search in some fields of text.

The problem is that I cannot find documents with capital letters, I know that this is something that must be configured in the moment of creating the index. But is it possible to search text with insensitive case even if I didn't configure that in the settings?.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can use custom analyzer that you want for `query_string`, This will ensure that the string you pass in will be analyzed with the one you provided. In your case, you should use the analyzer which converts the passed string to lowercase (for eg. `standard`)

```
{
   "query_string" : {"query" : "ABC", analyzer: "standard"}
}
```

Ref:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Comment: It didn't work, I don't know why because the documentation say that, but is ok, in the end I recreated the index. Thanks!